# Why do I see a black-and-white emoji in console with Noto Color Emoji font installed?

Tags: fonts, konsole, fontconfig, emoji

I have installed Noto Color Emoji font on my system (e.g. [Arch: noto-fonts-emoji](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/noto-fonts-emoji/)), but I still see this black-and-white version in the terminal (Konsole):

[image: Konsole showing echo command of the party popper emoji in black and white]

However, I expected the color one as displayed in other applications:

[image: KCharSelect application showing the party popper emoji]

[image: Emoji Selector application showing the party popper emoji]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The emojis are shown by the font selected in the terminal/console and the ones from the emoji fonts in color are not taking precedence over them. So it's basically the (limited) emoji support of your console font that masks the use of Noto Color Emoji.
One needs a fontconfig to raise the priority of the character (code points) in the emoji fonts to display those from the Noto Color Emoji font.

For Arch Linux, this is provided by the [AUR package noto-color-emoji-fontconfig](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/noto-color-emoji-fontconfig).
If you want to configure it manually, add [the fontconfig file](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/75-noto-color-emoji.conf?h=noto-color-emoji-fontconfig&id=f0677d458d56acf9f7665bb1e82b90ba6a497b06) there manually in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/75-noto-color-emoji.conf`.

Then restart the application (e.g. Konsole) and it should work:

[image: Konsole showing echo command of the party popper emoji in color]

Comment: This guide is also great https://christitus.com/emoji/